# Why can't I update rule's markdown note

Tags: sonarqube

Hi I am trying to update a Rule's markdown note:

```java
public Rule getRule(String key) {
    org.sonarqube.ws.client.rules.SearchRequest sr = new org.sonarqube.ws.client.rules.SearchRequest();
    sr.setRuleKey(key);
    List<Rule> rules = client.rules().search(sr).getRulesList();
    if(rules.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }else {
        return rules.get(0);
    }
} 

public void updateRule(Rule r) {
    org.sonarqube.ws.client.rules.UpdateRequest ur = new org.sonarqube.ws.client.rules.UpdateRequest();
    ur.setKey(r.getKey());
    ur.setMarkdownDescription(r.getMdDesc());
    ur.setMarkdownNote(r.getMdNote());
    ur.setName(r.getName());
    // TODO params
    // ur.setParams(r.getParams());
    ur.setRemediationFnBaseEffort(r.getRemFnBaseEffort());
    ur.setRemediationFnType(r.getRemFnType());
    ur.setRemediationFyGapMultiplier(r.getRemFnGapMultiplier());
    ur.setSeverity(r.getSeverity());
    ur.setStatus(r.getStatus().name());
    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0 ;i < r.getTags().getTagsCount(); i++) {
        tags.add(r.getTags().getTags(i));
    }
    if(!tags.isEmpty()) {
        ur.setTags(tags);
    }
    client.rules().update(ur);
}
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SonarApi sonarApi = new SonarApi("http://172.25.160.238:9876", "cac3b3c65347e87cdf1f9a7352935db79e2435f5");
    Rule r = sonarApi.getRule("java:S2204");
    Rule nr = Rule.newBuilder(r).setMdNote("xxx").build();
    System.out.println(nr.getKey());
    System.out.println(nr.getMdNote());
    sonarApi.updateRule(nr);
}
```

but it fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 400 on http://172.25.160.238:9876/api/rules/update : {"errors":[{"msg":"Not a custom rule"}]}
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse.java:36)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseService.call(BaseService.java:55)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseService.call(BaseService.java:50)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseService.call(BaseService.java:45)
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.rules.RulesService.update(RulesService.java:200)
    at com.bgzchina.devops.cq.sonar.SonarApi.updateRule(SonarApi.java:456)
    at com.bgzchina.devops.cq.sonar.SonarApi.main(SonarApi.java:465)
```

my sonarqube version: 9.1 (build 47736), the token is generated by administrator user. and I can update rule's markdown note from UI. Can anyone help ？